# Middlepoint on circle between 2 points

Tags: python, math, geometry

I'm trying to find middlepoint on the circle between 2 points, [pictorial drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgfEX.png)

There are given radius, p1, p2 and middle of the circle.

Distance betweeen p1 and p2 is an diameter, and I'm trying to make up python formula that returns point on the circle between those 2 points. I know this is rather silly question but I'm trying to make this for 3 hours now and all I can find on web is distance between those 2 points.

I'm trying to find formula for p3 (like in the picture)

That's what I ended up making so far:

```
import math

points = [[100, 200], [250, 350]]
midpoint = (int(((points[0][0] + points[1][0]) / 2)), int(((points[0][1] + points[1][1]) / 2)))
radius = int(math.sqrt(((points[1][0] - points[0][0])**2) + ((points[1][1] - points[0][1])**2))) // 2

# This below is wrong
print(int(midpoint[0] - math.sqrt((points[0][1] - midpoint[1]) ** 2)),
                 int(midpoint[1] - math.sqrt((points[0][0] - midpoint[1]) ** 2)))
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Edited question. I'm looking for formula for third point that lies in between 2 given on circle. Mathematical or in Python

Comment: This seems to be more a math than a Python question.

Comment: There are 2 midpoints between every pair of points on the circle. Is there the idea that the order of the point and a circle orientation ((anti-)clockwise) determine which midpoint to chose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for trigonometry, which is total overkill.

The center of the circle is `Xs= (X1 + X2) / 2`, `Ys= (Y1 + Y2) / 2`.

The two opposite "middlepoints" are given by `X3 = Xs - (Y1 - Ys)`, `Y3 = Ys + (X1 - Xs)` and `X4 = Xs + (Y1 - Ys)`, `Y4 = Ys - (X1 - Xs)`.

If you prefer direct formulas, `X3 = (X1 + X2 - Y1 + Y2) / 2`, `Y3 = (X1 - X2 + Y1 + Y2) / 2`...

Answer (score 0):

To generate points on the circle use polar equation (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154550/polar-equation-of-a-circle)

```
import math
import random

points = [[100, 200], [250, 350]]
midpoint = (int(((points[0][0] + points[1][0]) / 2)), int(((points[0][1] + points[1][1]) / 2)))
radius = int(math.sqrt(((points[1][0] - points[0][0])**2) + ((points[1][1] - points[0][1])**2))) // 2

angle = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)
x_relative = radius * math.cos(angle)
y_relative = radius * math.sin(angle)

x = midpoint[0] + x_relative
y = midpoint[1] + y_relative

print(f"{x} {y}")
```

To find middle point on the circle between points:

```
import math

points = [[100, 200], [250, 350]]
midpoint = (int(((points[0][0] + points[1][0]) / 2)), int(((points[0][1] + points[1][1]) / 2)))
radius = int(math.sqrt(((points[1][0] - points[0][0])**2) + ((points[1][1] - points[0][1])**2))) // 2

points_relative = [[points[0][0] - midpoint[0], points[0][1] - midpoint[1]], [points[1][0] - midpoint[0], points[1][1] - midpoint[1]]]

midpoint_points_relative = [[points_relative[0][1], - points_relative[0][0]], [points_relative[1][1], - points_relative[1][0]]]
midpoint_points = [[midpoint_points_relative[0][0] + midpoint[0], midpoint_points_relative[0][1] + midpoint[1]], [midpoint_points_relative[1][0] + midpoint[0], midpoint_points_relative[1][1] + midpoint[1]]]

print(points)
print(midpoint)
print(points_relative)

print(midpoint_points)
```

You can use this page to test results: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mhq4hsncnh

Comment: thanks a lot, really helped me and pushed forward my project

Comment: @BaćkoKaczor Look at simple and effective way in Yves' answer. Note that vector approach helps to simplify solutions of many geometric problems.